# XNIO: How to get notified when a connection is closed?

Tags: java, nio

I'm trying to write a server using XNIO. I want to get notified when a client closes connection to the server.

```
XnioWorker worker = Xnio.getInstance().createWorker(OptionMap.EMPTY);

AcceptingChannel<StreamConnection> server = worker.createStreamConnectionServer(
        new InetSocketAddress(0), acceptingChannel -> {
            try {
                StreamConnection connection = acceptingChannel.accept();
                if (connection != null) {
                    System.out.println("accepted");

                    connection.setCloseListener(channel -> System.out.println("closed"));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, OptionMap.EMPTY);
server.resumeAccepts();
```

I attach a close listener to each new connection. The problem is that it is never invoked.

For example, if I connect to server

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(server.getLocalAddress());
```

and then disconnect

```
socket.close();
System.out.println("client connection closed");
```

I can see only the following lines in my console

```
accepted
client connection closed
```

But there is no message from the close listener. Is there a way to get such notifications?

**Update**

Ok, I can learn when the peer shutdowns writes. Then I can close source channel:

```
ConduitStreamSourceChannel sourceChannel = connection.getSourceChannel();
sourceChannel.setReadListener(channel -> {
    try {
        int byteNum = channel.read(buffer);
        if (byteNum == -1) channel.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
sourceChannel.resumeReads();
```

But what's about sink channel? In other words, how can I distinguish whether the peer completely closes the connection

```
socket.close();
```

or half closes it?

```
socket.getOutputStream().close();
```

**Update 2**

There is no need to close source channel explicitly when reading. XNIO does this by itself.

```
ConduitStreamSourceChannel sourceChannel = connection.getSourceChannel();
sourceChannel.setReadListener(channel -> {
    try {
        channel.read(buffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
sourceChannel.resumeReads();
```

Still the question remains: how can I get to know when the peer fully disconnects vs closes only writes?

Comment: In general, you have to read from the connection, to see the FIN from the peer. There's no other way in most socket APIs.

Comment: There's no other way in *any* API. At the bottom, Berkeley Sockets API level, the only mechanism for detecting end of stream is a read.

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching your listener to the downstream channel instead :

```
connection.getSourceChannel()
    .setCloseListener((ch)->System.out.println("client connection closed"));

//At some level you need to make sure your source channel is enabling reads.
connection.getSourceChannel().resumeReads();
```

The 'close' listener attached to the `StreamConnection` will get called only if both the SourceChannel (downstream channel) & the SinkChannel (upstream channel) are closed.

**EDIT: (Full Example)**

Server :

```
XnioWorker worker = Xnio.getInstance().createWorker(OptionMap.EMPTY);

AcceptingChannel<StreamConnection> server = worker.createStreamConnectionServer(
    new InetSocketAddress(0), acceptingChannel -> {
        try {
            StreamConnection connection = acceptingChannel.accept();
            if (connection != null) {
                System.out.println("accepted");

                connection.setCloseListener(channel -> System.out.println("closed"));
            }
            ConduitStreamSourceChannel sourceChannel = connection.getSourceChannel();
            ConduitStreamSinkChannel sinkChannel = connection.getSinkChannel();

            sourceChannel
                        .setCloseListener((t)->System.out.println("Source Closed"));
            sinkChannel
                        .setCloseListener((t)->System.out.println("Sink Closed"));

            sourceChannel.setReadListener((channel)->{
                    try{
                        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(15);
                        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                        while(sourceChannel.read(bb) > 0){
                            bb.flip();
                            while(bb.position() < bb.limit()){
                                builder.append((char)bb.get());
                            }
                            bb.clear();
                        }
                        System.out.println(builder.toString());
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });

            sourceChannel.resumeReads();
            sinkChannel.resumeWrites();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }, OptionMap.EMPTY);

server.resumeAccepts();
```

Client:

```
try(Socket client = new Socket(Server.SERVER_HOST,Server.SERVER_PORT);
        PrintWriter echoWriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);)
    {
        echoWriter.println("Hello");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        client.close();
        //your Server Source Channel close listener will notify you from here
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Under the scope of the initial question (before the update) it did work, didn't it?

Comment: No, it did not. If I don't close the channel manually the listener is not invoked.

Comment: I've updated the answer to illustrate my example, is this example working for you ?

Comment: Yes, now the source channel is closed. But the sink channel and the connection remain open.

Comment: StreamConnection and Source/Sink channels are xnio levels abstractions. In TCP protocol, there are no such notifications (such as i'm still 'listenning' but won't 'tell' you anything anymore) so i'm afraid that what you're trying to achieve isn't doable. 
It seems however strange to me why closing either InputStream or OutputStream at the client level end up with a close event triggered by the SourceStream.